# docker-compose - cannot use bind mount in folder created when using BUILD

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file which uses a Dockerfile to build the image. In this image (Dockerfile) I created the folder `/workspace` which I'd like to bind mount for persistence in my local filesystem.

After the docker-compose up, the folder is empty if I bind mount, but if I do not mount this folder everything works fine (and the folder exist with all the files I added).

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: uwsgi --ini /workspace/confs/uwsgi.ini --logger file:/workspace/logs/uswgi.log --processes 1 --workers 1 --plugins-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/ --plugin=python
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=***
      - DB_USER=***
      - DB_PASS=***
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - memcached
    volumes:
      - ./workspace:/workspace
    networks:
      - asyncmail
      - traefik
# db, redis and memcached are ommited here
# aditional labels for traefik is also ommited
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN mkdir /workspace
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y 
RUN apt-get install -y redis-server python3-pip git-core postgresql-client
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev python3-dev libffi-dev libtiff5-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg8-dev libyaml-dev libpython3-dev openssh-client uwsgi-plugin-python3 libpcre3 libpcre3-dev uwsgi-plugin-python

ADD myapp /workspace/
WORKDIR /workspace/src/
RUN /bin/bash -c "pip3 install cffi \
    && pip3 install -r /workspace/src/requirements.txt \
    && ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime

# CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "/workspace/confs/uwsgi.ini", "--logger", "file:/workspace/logs/uswgi.log"]
```

- I know there is some items it could be optimized, but when I do a `docker-compose up -d` the folder ./workspace is created with only a folder inside called `src`. Inside the container the /workspace only have this empty folder too;
- If I remove the volumes line in docker-compose, inside the container, the folder /workspace have all the sourcecode of my app.

What am I doing wrong that I can't bind mount the workspace folder?

PS: I know this image i'm using (ubuntu trusty) is old, but my old app only run with this version.

Comment: If you bind-mount a host directory over a container directory, whatever contents existed in the host directory _always_ hide what was built in the image.  This means you don't usually want to bind-mount a directory over the directory that contains your actual application; maybe you want a separate `/workspace/data` directory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

am I correct in assuming that the files you want to appear inside workspace are actually in a folder called "myapp" in your host machine
(it seems so from this line)

`ADD myapp /workspace/`

I think you meant to map that into your docker container, so under volumes

```
volumes:
      - ./myapp:/workspace
```

volume maps work one way, that is the folder inside the container is replaced by the contents of the mapped folder on the host, not the other way around...

Comment: 1) yes, myapp is the folder with source code;
2) about the folder inside the container being replaced by the contents of the mapped folder, I understand that the other way around also works - thing in the postgresql container when the first time started, he copy the data folder inside the container to the host file system in the bind folder.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with adding to the container the sourcecode directory to fix this problem. @NiRR answer helped a lot.

The final Dockerfile was changes to not include sourcecode in the image:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y 
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip git-core postgresql-client
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev python3-dev libffi-dev libtiff5-dev zlib1g-dev libjpeg8-dev libyaml-dev libpython3-dev openssh-client uwsgi-plugin-python3 libpcre3 libpcre3-dev

WORKDIR /workspace/src
COPY myapp/src/requirements.txt .
RUN /bin/bash -c "pip3 install cffi \
    && pip3 install -r requirements.txt"

# To set timezone
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime
```

And I changed the docker-compose to the following final version:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: ./start.sh
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=***
      - DB_USER=***
      - DB_PASS=***
    volumes:
      - ./myapp:/workspace
```

- Now in the container start all the sourcecode from myapp is copied to inside the container;
- Everything is under GIT control
- If the code changes, we can make a push/pull and `docker-compose up -d` to restart the container. The new version will already be there.